# Downloading GZIP file in T-SQL, Extracting XML within

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, gzip

Is it possible from T-SQL script to download a GZIP file (either tar archived or not, in my case they are not)  from a `HTTP` or `HTTPS` source using `BASIC AUTHENTICATION`, extract its contents (in my case a single XML file) and pass extracted file's text contents to an already built SP as an `XML` type parameter, and fire this off on a schedule, say once a day?

Where would i start?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) then that would probably be the route I'd take. Create a package to do the above and schedule via SQL Server Agent.

Comment: I hear SSIS is only available for SQL Developer, SQL Standard and <, if i use SSIS to develop my database, do you know if i can deploy the end result in SQLEXPRESS?

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know if SQL Express supports SSIS but I think it's unlikely.